# How change all the href with a specific url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, href

I want to change all the urls of the href = "" that are in my home page, but it is a specific url.

Example:

```
<a href="mydomain.com/issues/resolve"> The issue </a>
```

Switch to:

```
<a href = "mydomain.com/issues/resolve/#thecontent">The issue</a>
```

I clarify that there is more than one   with the same url, I want to change them all.

I have tried this without any visible result this I am doing with javascript:

```
$enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

                  for (let i = 0; i < $enlaces.length; i++) {
                    $enlaces2 = $enlaces[i];

                    if ($enlaces[i].href == 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve') {
                        this.href = 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve/#thecontent';
                    }

                    console.log ($enlaces2);

                  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `<a>` node [has many properties](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_anchor.asp).

Given:

- **HTML:** `<a href="https://www.example.com:80/this/is/the/path?foo=bar&bish=bash#myAnchor" >test link</a>`,
- **javascript member representing the resulting DOM node:** `link`,

then the properties of interest here are:

- **link.href** `https://www.example.com:80/this/is/the/path?foo=bar&bish=bash#testSector`
- **link.hostname** `www.example.com`
- **link.pathname** `/this/is/the/path`
- **link.hash** `myAnchor`

These and other properties are read/write.

So from the question, you appear to want to test `a.hostname + a.pathname`. If so then the following will do what you want:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ((this.hostname + this.pathname) == 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve') {
        this.hash = 'thecontent';
    }
});
```

You should see why testing the `.href` property didn't work.

Notes:

- reading: `a.hash` returns a string including the leading `#`
- writing: `a.hash = "someString"` does not require the hash.
- there were historical differences between browsers in this regard but I think they are ironed out now (worth testing).

Answer (score 0):

Because `$enlaces[i].href` give you **your_domain** + `href` value, So the condition in if clause would not happen.

You need to get exact `href` value by using `attr('href')` like below

```js
$enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (let i = 0; i < $enlaces.length; i++) {
  $enlaces2 = $enlaces[i];
  var href_DOM_value = $($enlaces[i]).attr('href');
  var href_Actual_value = $enlaces[i].href;
  console.log(href_DOM_value);
  console.log(href_Actual_value);
  
  if (href_DOM_value == 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve') {
      $($enlaces2).attr('href', 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve/#thecontent');
      console.log("changed");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="mydomain.com/issues/resolve"> The issue </a>
```

Comment: Hello Phong, what I try to do is go through all the links (<a href = "") that are on the website home page and search for the specific url to change it how I want, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You label this a jQuery question, and i´ll give you a jQuery answer:

```
$("a").each(function(){
if($(this).atrr("href")=="mydomain.com/issues/resolve/")
 $(this).atrr("href","mydomain.com/issues/resolve/#thecontent");
});
```

That said, is a bad practice using == "mydomain.com/issues/resolve/" as usually href atributes contain protocols, so I would use indexOf instead

```
$("a").each(function(){
if($(this).atrr("href").indexOf("mydomain.com/issues/resolve/") >= 0)
 $(this).atrr("href","mydomain.com/issues/resolve/#thecontent");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you solution is "this" isn't defined. I may be higher up the chain, but it isn't set by the for loop. What you want is more like

```
$enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

                  for (let i = 0; i < $enlaces.length; i++) {
                    $enlaces2 = $enlaces[i];

                    if ($enlaces[i].href == 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve') {
                        $enlaces[i].href = 'mydomain.com/issues/resolve/#thecontent';
                    }

                    console.log ($enlaces2);

                  }
```

Some of the other answers may address additional problems, such as the href giving a full url with scheme, not necessarily the relative url. I'm not sure your example urls are even valid. Need a scheme or at least // at the start.